# Ionic 2 Events, publish and subscribe not working

Tags: angularjs, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, dom-events

I'm trying to use `Publish` and `Subscribe` from ionic-angular

But I am not receiving any data nor error. Here are my codes

Page 1

```
import {Events} from 'ionic-angular'

static get parameters(){
 return [[Events]];
}

constructor(Events)
{
 this.events = Events;

 this.events.publish("Msg", "Hello World");
}
```

Page 2

```
import {Events} from 'ionic-angular'

static get parameters(){
 return [[Events]];
}

constructor(Events)
{
 this.events = Events;

 this.events.subscribe("Msg", (data) => {
  console.log(data[0]);
 }
}
```

I'm using `ionic-angular beta0.4`.

---

I realize why it doesn't show on console.. Page 2 has to be loaded and ready before Page 1 initiate an event. If Page 1 were to initiate and publish before Page 2 is even loaded, Page 2 will not be able to grab that data.

**SOLVED**

Comment: Have you tried with changing the import with `import {Events} from 'ionic-angular';`

Comment: @sebaferreras Thanks I did try that, nevertheless I realize why it doesn't show on console.. Page 2 has to be loaded and ready before Page 1 initiate an event. If Page 1 were to initiate and publish before Page 2 is even loaded, Page 2 will not be able to grab that data.

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Comment: Just a small observation, I don't really know why do you need to use events in your app, but please keep in mind that you could also use a **shared service** to make different pages communicate with each others. That would be the recommended way to handle communication in an Ionic2 App. If you want, I can include a plunker with a demo.

Comment: @sebaferreras hello, that would be great! I would need to use event as I'm constantly listening to my internet status on my first page, and I would like something to happen when my network is off on my second page

Comment: Just a word of warning, events.publish will silently fail with no output on the console if something caused it to throw an exception. I spent hours wondering why events failed on me only to realize there was an error in the subscriber but no error shown in the browser console.

Comment: @sebaferreras how to force page2 to load without having to travel to it initially (ie. via tab.select). In my case it is hosted in a different tab.

Answer (score 2):

> I would need to use event as I'm constantly listening to my internet
>   status on my first page, and I would like something to happen when my
>   network is off on my second page

In the app I'm working right now, we're doing exactly the same. Please take a look at this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jbNSjI?p=preview).

As you can see there, I've created a `ConnectivityService` whose main goal is to be informed when the connection status has changed (by your first page), and then notify to all the subscribers about that (your second page -and every page if you want-)

ConnectivityService.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class ConnectivityService { 

  private connectionObserver: any;
  public connection: any;

  constructor(){
    this.connectionObserver = null;
    this.connection = Observable.create(observer => {
        this.connectionObserver = observer;
    });
  }

  // Send that information to all the subscribers
  public connectionHasChanged(private isOnline: bool) {
      this.connectionObserver.next(isOnline);
  }
}
```

With that being done, we just need to register the 'online' and 'offline' events in your first page (or do it like you're doing it in your app) and notify the service when the connection status changes:

App.ts

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { ionicBootstrap, Platform } from 'ionic-angular/index';
import { HomePage } from './home.ts';
import { ConnectivityService } from 'connectivityService.ts';

@Component({
  template: '<ion-nav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>',
  providers: [ConnectivityService]
})
export class MyApp {
  constructor(private platform: Platform, private connectivityService: ConnectivityService) {
    this.addConnectivityListeners();
    this.rootPage = HomePage;
  }

  // Subscribe to online/offline events
  addConnectivityListeners(){

    // Handle online event
    document.addEventListener('online', () => {
      // Call the service, to indicate now there's connection (true)
      this.connectivityService.connectionHasChanged(true);
    }, false);

    // Handle offline event
    document.addEventListener('offline', () => {
      // Call the service, to indicate now there's no connection (false)
      this.connectivityService.connectionHasChanged(false);
    }, false);
  }
}

ionicBootstrap(MyApp);
```

And last but not least, then in your second page (or every page you need to) you can just subscribe to that service and handle the events

Home.ts

```
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular/index';
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { ConnectivityService } from 'connectivityService.ts';

@Component({
  templateUrl:"home.html"
})
export class HomePage {

  public status: string = '';

  constructor(private nav: NavController, private connectivityService: ConnectivityService) {

    // We subscribe to the service, so if the connection status changes, we'll be notified.
    this.connectivityService.connection.subscribe((isOnline) => {
      this.handleConnectionStatus(isOnline);
    });
  }

  // Show a message when the connection changes
  public handleConnectionStatus(private isOnline: bool) {
    if(isOnline) {
      this.status = 'Online';
      console.log('Now is Online');
    } else {
      this.status = 'Offline';
      console.log('Now is offline');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How to force another page hosted in a another tab to load without the user traveling to that tab. So that page eg. About would have subscribed to your events approach?  Thanks

Comment: I don't think your Plunker is pointing to anything specific -- can you check your link?

Comment: I'm sorry @VariousArtist, the plunker is old and seems like it was removed. I'll create a StackBlitz project with the same code and will update the link in the answer. Thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: In the question is using ionic event model where page 2 is having problem with .subscribe & this solution maybe good but totally different approach

Answer (score 0):

Having read the posts here and other forums, seems like the part about subscribing to an event is rather tricky. I gather that understanding lifecycle hooks and how promises work is important to getting around the problem. The following works if you want a second page to be able to subscribe to a published event on an existing page:

```
this.navCtrl.setRoot(NextComponentPage, Parameters).then(()=>
{
    this.events.publish("user:created", userdetails);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the **.subscribe** inside **constructor**.

and insted of ***console.log(data[0])*** have you tried with **console.log(data)** ?