# Registering a connection event in ionic 2

Tags: javascript, google-maps, events, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am new to ionic 2, I am trying to create an event and listen for changes to that event. The event would be triggered if the network connection state of my app changes. I am currently doing this in a provider called Connectivity and instantiating the provider in my root component. then in one of my pages, which i call maps which is another provider, maps uses the event created in the connectivity provider to check for connection then display a map. The problem is, the event does not seem to be triggered, and my map is not generated. here is my code

```js
// connectivity provider

@Injectable()
export class Connectivity {

  onDevice: boolean = true;

  constructor( public platform: Platform, private events: Events){
    this.onDevice = this.platform.is('cordova');
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.isOnline();
      this.watchForNetworkChanges();
    })
  }

  isOnline(): void {
    if(this.onDevice && Network.type){
      this.events.publish('network:connected', Network.type !== Connection.NONE);
    } else {
      this.events.publish('network:connected', navigator.onLine);
    }
  }

  watchForNetworkChanges(): void {
    // Watch network for a connection
    Network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
      this.events.publish('network:connected', true);
    });

    Network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
      this.events.publish('network:connected', false);
    });
  }
}


//my maps provider

  constructor(private events: Events){}

  init(mapElement: any, pleaseConnect: any){

    this.mapElement = mapElement;
    this.pleaseConnect = pleaseConnect;
    this.loadGoogleMaps();
  }

  loadGoogleMaps() {
    this.events.subscribe('network:connected', (status) => {
      let connected = status
      if (!connected) {
        this.disableMap();
      }
      else {
        this.initMap().then(function () {
          this.enableMap();
        })
      }
    });
  }
  
  // home.page.ts
  
  @ViewChild('map') mapElement: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('pleaseConnect') pleaseConnect: ElementRef;

  constructor(public platform: Platform, public maps: GoogleMaps) {
    this.showList = false;
    this.initializeItems();
    this.homePageStart();
  }

  homePageStart(){
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.maps.init(this.mapElement.nativeElement, this.pleaseConnect.nativeElement);
    });
  }
```

Comment: have you subscribed to "network:connected" anywhere else?

Comment: for now i only subscribe to "network:connected" in my maps provider.

Comment: Did you log inside subscribe?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is with `this` here:

```
 this.initMap().then(function () {
          this.enableMap();
        })
```

Since you are using function, the `this` points to the function object and not the class. Try using `()=>{}` which has lexical scoping and takes the `this object` of the class.

```
 this.initMap().then(()=> {
      this.enableMap();
    })
```

Documentation for [**Arrow Functions**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: i added a console.log before and in the subscribe of maps. I see the log before the subscribe but not in the subscribe. I also added a log before the event is published and that got logged out. I changed to arrow functions also. I still don't see my map. If i remove the check for connection my map does get displayed.

Comment: `let connected = status[0] === true;` why are you checking `status[0]` when you are sending true or false directly? It should be `let connected = status;`

Comment: I was sending a different value before and forgot to take that line out.

Comment: I dont see any other issue with syntax..maybe the multiple publish actions are sending contradictory? I would say try debug that.

Comment: Thanks!! is this a better way of checking for connection? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38342171/ionic-2-events-publish-and-subscribe-not-working or is the way i am trying to do okay, if i can get it to work?

Comment: as far as I know events publish/subscribe is the best way to handle it..maybe use different strings for `onDevice` and `network change`?

Comment: Okay, ill keep working on it. I will post my solution when i resolve this.